# Change in RecordTypeId is not refreshing lightning-record-form

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter, lightning-recordeditform, getobjectinfo

I am creating a lwc component form which creates a new Opportunity using lightning-record-form and a default recordtypeid value.

As there is no option to select recordtypes in lightning-record-form, I have created a separate component, which displays the list of all record types for Opportunity.

I am trying to refresh the lightning-record-form once the user selects a different record type in the second component.

My issue here is that once the user selects a different record type, the lightning-record-form sometimes gets refreshed and sometimes it doesn't and displays the same fields as that of the previously selected record type.

In createNewOpportunity.html, I have the following code

```
    <div>
        <c-record-type-selector object-api-name={objectApiName}
                                onrecordtypechangeevent={recordTypeChange}>

        </c-record-type-selector>
    </div>
    <div>
        <lightning-record-form   
            object-api-name={objectApiName}
            mode={mode}
            layout-type={layoutType}
            columns={columns}
            record-type-id={recordTypeId}>
        </lightning-record-form>
    </div>
```

In createNewOpportunity.js I have the following code

```
@wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: '$objectApiName' })


getObjectInfo({ error, data }) {
    console.log('Is this getting called?');
    if (data) {
        this.lstFields = [];
        for (let key in data.fields) {
            if (data.fields.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                this.lstFields.push({fieldApiName: key, objectApiName:this.objectApiName});
            }
        }
        const rtis = data.recordTypeInfos;
        this.recordTypeId = Object.keys(rtis).find(rti => rtis[rti].name === 'Client');
        console.log('this.recordTypeId ::: '+this.recordTypeId);
    }
    else if (error) {
        console.log('Error while get fields');
        this.lstFields = [];
    }
}
```

I also have a method on createNewOpportunity.js which passes the changed recordtype id from the child component to the parent. The changes record type id is coming up correctly without any issue and I can see the changes recordTypeId value in the console.log.

```
recordTypeChange(event) {
    const recordTypeValue = event.detail;
    console.log('Record Type Value ::: '+recordTypeValue);
    this.recordTypeId = recordTypeValue;
    return refreshApex(this.getObjectInfo); //I tried using this to refresh but it didn't work
}
```